# Need advice on project layout for Play 2.2 submodule with other modules as dependencies

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

I have an existing SBT project with modules. I want to add Play 2.2 into my project as a submodule. This new Play module will depend on other modules.

What I found so far was mostly about Play being the main project with supporting modules. If Play does support this setup, please point me in the right direction how to do it. Thanks.

My intended setup (simplified):

```
my_project
\--- desktop_ui
     \--- src/main
     \--- src/test
\--- common
     \--- src/main
     \--- src/test
\--- web_ui (Play framework)
     \--- app/controllers
     \--- app/views
     \--- app/models
     \--- conf
```

Comment: Yes, I have done this. It is possible. You will still have `project/Build.scala`. This will be the build file for your main project. Which version of Play are you using? 2.0, 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: Play 2.2. How do I modify my project/Build.scala to build Play apps and to generate Play application key?

Comment: I think you should make `web_ui` the main project (you can still have it in a subdirectory). Then your `desktop_ui` and `common` will both be subprojects. That's how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1) have an 'empty' main project aggregating your 3 sub-projects:

```
root
\--- project
    \--- Build.scala
\--- web_ui
\--- common
\--- desktop_ui
```

And in Build.scala something like this:

```
lazy val common = Project(id = "common", base = file("common"))
lazy val desktopUi = Project(id = "desktop_ui", base = file("desktop_ui")
lazy val webUi = play.Project(name = "web_ui", path = file("web_ui"))
.dependsOn(common, desktopUi)
```

lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).aggregate(common, desktopUi, webUi)

With this option, you can start sbt from the root folder and build all your projects. You also define all the settings, dependencies in this unique build definition.

2) Another layout can be used to keep your sub-projects independent from each other. I tend to prefer this way because it's cleaner (e.g. I can work on `common` as an independent project, not as a submodule) but it is not as convenient to build the whole system.

```
root
\--- web_ui
    \--- project
        \--- Build.scala
\--- common
     \--- project
        \--- Build.scala
\--- desktop_ui
     \--- project
        \--- Build.scala
```

Here, each project is independent (you can use build.sbt instead of Build.scala if you want, see sbt documentation) and in web_ui/project/Build.scala :

```
lazy val common = RootProject(file("../common"))
lazy val desktopUi = RootProject(file("../desktop_ui"))

val main = play.Project(name = "web_ui", path = file("web_ui")).dependsOn(common, desktopUi)
```

Here, root is just used to gather everything in one folder, then the play project references the other modules.

Answer (score 4):

[Play 2.2 supports sbt 0.13](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22) so to use it for your expected project layout I'd recommend to have the following `build.sbt` in the `my_project` root project:

```
import play.Project._

lazy val my_project = project in file(".") aggregate (desktop_ui, common, web_ui)

lazy val desktop_ui = project dependsOn common

lazy val common = project

// no need to dependsOn "common" since it's already a dependency of "desktop_ui"
lazy val web_ui = play.Project(name = "web_ui", path = file("web_ui"))
                    .dependsOn(desktop_ui)
```

Since `my_project` uses Play 2.2 class - `play.Project` - to define a Play project, `project/plugins.sbt` is required.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2-RC1")
```

That might explain why Play module is usually a top-level one (since so much is needed in the top-level project that it effectively becomes a Play module).

The complete project layout is as follows:

```
$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    └── plugins.sbt

1 directory, 3 files
```

What's quite interesting is that even without all the project directories and no Play project in place (just a definition in the `build.sbt`) you can still `run` the `web_ui` project and access it with your web browser (!) It will fail for obvious reasons, but shows there's not much needed to get running with sbt and Play.

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/project/}my_project-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to my_project (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/)
[my_project]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/
[info]     common
[info]     desktop_ui
[info]   * my_project
[info]     web_ui
[my_project]> project web_ui
[info] Set current project to web_ui (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/)
[web_ui]> run
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/}common...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/}desktop_ui...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/play-2.2-multi/my_project/}web_ui...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Comment: I assume I have to provide a Build.scala (single or multiple Build.scala depending on how I laid out my projects) for common and desktop_ui to include dependency on 3rd party libraries. Am I right?

Comment: @thlim quite the contrary. You can use the root's `build.sbt` or create a separate `build.sbt` for every submodule and use it to configure them. Start with [.sbt Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) and then hop onto  [Multi-Project Builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html).