# Multi-Project SBT Builds with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm trying to build a **Multi-Project Builds using sbt** with a Play Framework project.

```
|-- core (**many external dependancy**)
|   `-- src
|       `-- main
|           `-- scala
|               `-- com
|                   `-- VeryComplexStuff.scala
|-- playWebsite
|   `-- [...]
|
`-- project
    |-- Build.scala
    |-- assembly.sbt
    |-- build.properties
    |-- plugins.sbt
    `-- sbt-updates.sbt
```

How can the project "playWebsite" dependOn "core" ? 
Of course I try to simplify, in reality I have many project who depend on core.

Obviously this is a very common problem but I can't find any solution.
Is it maybe because I'm not going in the right direction ? 
Maybe core should be a "standalone" project with it own Build.scala ?

---

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/SBTSubProjects 
It doesn't look to fit me. I don't want a sub-project, I want to depend on an "higher lever" project.

https://github.com/kifi/multiproject 
I don't want to merge multiple play project

#### EDIT:

Maybe this is the way to go ?
[Need advice on project layout for Play 2.2 submodule with other modules as dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925291/need-advice-on-project-layout-for-play-2-2-submodule-with-other-modules-as-depen)

Answer (score 2):

in your main build (project/Build.scala or build.sbt) define:

```
lazy val core = project in file("core") settings(...) 

lazy val play = project in file("playWebsite") settings(...) dependsOn(core)
```

that's about it...